# Image Folder - Structure and Naming

Tags: naming-conventions, semantics, naming

I am interested to see if anyone has some good ideas/best practice for the folder names and structure of their image folders, plus the naming of the actual images.

A non-important question but one that has been bugging me. At the end of a build I can end up with an overflowing image folder - mostly in one giant list. I try to name my images with what I think is a form of logic e.g. location_purpose_measurements.

For a website we can split it into 'header', 'footer', 'article' etc, but for the images different rules should surely apply. hrd_logo_224x45.jpg is great in respect that I know its a logo for the header and its measurements. Semantically though the use of 'hdr' would confuse things in the future if for some reason the client wanted it used in the footer instead or in amongst the main content. Creating a folder in the images folder called 'header' could also confuse things. Or, following the semantic layout of a webpage, should the folder structure mirror this - header, footer, article, navigation?

e.g.

img
   branding
   navigation
   gallery
      apples
      oranges
   structure

Comment: Usually I separate images by purpose like users, companies, icons, etc. But that images that are used in site layout I just keep in images folder with no structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best practice is to first layout database for images and then folders and filenames accordingly. For example you could have several tables for categories (icons, fancy_page_elements, public_images, something) and then each table has its own structure for elements. for example table icons could look like `id | icon_set | ext`
Then img folder basically boils down to:
`.img/category/param1/param2/paramn/id.ext`
Of course this works for really large imagebase. And most probably you would like to have one big table with image ids and some EXIF or similar data in order not to have duplicate image names (even in different subfolders). Hope you can get some ideas from this (:

Comment: Thanks for the input :) Its all about the perfect semantic naming structure etc for code but when it comes to images and the image folder most people, myself included, tend to dump.

Comment: The problem with images is that most of them are "art", therefore it is impossible to exactly describe what's inside (unlike source code files). Therefore most naming schemes tend to become suffixed with numbers and no longer serve their purpose. Furthermore, naming schemes are mostly used to LOCATE particular file, which is a way easier with database, categories and tags

Comment: Ya, quite a few are what would be classed as 'art' and I am not too bothered about them, it's more the images used to make up the structure of the website. I build a semantic website but feel the images, of which there are usually many, lack a structure. Annoyingly I don't think semantic rules applied to webpages should be applied to the image folder due to multiple use of an image. I guess its also the annoyance that I have this neat and tidy semantic website and then a messy huge non-ordered image folder, it's like ying and yang.